# Using predict() and calculating manually in Logistic regression in R does not match. What is the reason?

Tags: r, glm, predict

When I run logistic regression and use predict() function and when I manually calculate with formula p=1/(1+e^-(b0+b1*x1...)) I cannot get the same answer. What could be the reason?

```
>test[1,]
      loan_status loan_Amount interest_rate period      sector    sex age grade
10000           0         608      41.72451     12 Online Shop Female  44    D3
```

sector and period was insignificant so I removed it from the regression.
glm gives:

```
 Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -1.1542256  0.7610472  -1.517  0.12936    
interest_rate -0.0479765  0.0043415 -11.051  < 2e-16 ***
sexMale       -0.8814945  0.0656296 -13.431  < 2e-16 ***
age           -0.0139100  0.0035193  -3.953 7.73e-05 ***
gradeB         0.3209587  0.8238955   0.390  0.69686    
gradeC1       -0.7113279  0.8728260  -0.815  0.41509    
gradeC2       -0.4730014  0.8427544  -0.561  0.57462    
gradeC3        0.0007541  0.7887911   0.001  0.99924    
gradeD1        0.5637668  0.7597531   0.742  0.45806    
gradeD2        1.3207785  0.7355950   1.796  0.07257 .  
gradeD3        0.9201400  0.7303779   1.260  0.20774    
gradeE1        1.7245351  0.7208260   2.392  0.01674 *  
gradeE2        2.1547773  0.7242669   2.975  0.00293 ** 
gradeE3        3.1163245  0.7142881   4.363 1.28e-05 ***
```

```
>predictions_1st <- predict(Final_Model, newdata = test[1,], type = "response")
>predictions_1st
answer: **0.05478904**
```

But when I calculate like this:

```
>prob_1 <- 1/(1+e^-((-0.0479764603)*41.72451)-0.0139099563*44)
>prob_1
answer: 0.09081154
```

I calculated also with insignificant coefficients but answer still is not the same. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have also an `(Intercept) -1.1542256` and a `gradeD3 0.9201400`

```
1/(1+exp(-1*(-1.1542256 -0.0479764603*41.72451 -0.0139099563*44 + 0.9201400)))
#[1] 0.05478904
```

Comment: I did that calculation as well, but I used the same variable to calculate many cases and it gave me different answers. If I create new variable then it corrects it (I still don't know why it does that). Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tsotne Maybe the other data lines have different `grade`. This works only for `D3`.